# jQuery Isotope with clickable boxes and a filtering menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

With jQuery [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) I'd really like to have system as they have on the demo page called [Centered Masonry](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html) but the code that page is a little to complex for me to get my head around. However I have found something close to what I'm after on [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/S5vAG/2/light/) but it doesn't incorporate a menu/filters like it has on the CM demo page, is there any way I can add one?

Thanks.

Comment: I do but I don't see the stats anywhere? and a lot of the time people seem to answers in the comment boxes.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is looking for the answer I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jQVAg/4/) and it's pretty close.